# Copy vendor/cache gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I have a set of old gems I can't install from internet.

My plan is to copy what is in production server to my local environment.

1. `gem env` to know where gems are being installed.
2. `cd to_gems_dir`
3. there are a of of folders there,
4. I copied `cache` folder to my local machine
5. under `vendor/cache` inside project folder.
6. run bundle to check everything is OK.

But is not, bundler tries to install some gems, some others not. I don't know too much about bundler and gems envs, so my question is what am I doing wrong here? any other ideas to replicate remote gem set in my local machine?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did:

```
for file in vendor/cache/*; do gem i --local $file; done
```

Then all gems where installed, finally:

```
bundle check
The Gemfile's dependencies are satisfied
```